# ctest doesn't seem to use the settings in CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE

Tags: linux, windows, cmake

After making my application work on Linux, I'm trying cross-compile it for Windows and MacOSX.  I already use CMake.

I began by creating a toolchain file. This works.  My linux program is compiled with mingw and I receive a .exe at the end.

```
# build linux
$ cmake -Bbuild-linux
$ cmake --build build-linux

# build windows
$ cmake -Bbuild-windows -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`pwd`/cmake/x86_64-w64-mingw32.cmake
$ cmake --build build-windows
```

What happens next, is I run ctest to execute the unit tests.  In Linux, this works fine.  But when I do this using the cross-compiled stuff, it can't find the .exe file.

```
# run tests linux
(cd build-linux; ctest)

# run tests windows
(cd build-windows; ctest)
```

No problem, I thought -- I would append the .exe suffix depending on the environment -- using `if(WIN32)`

```
# CMakeLists.txt

if(WIN32)
    SET(EXE_SUFFIX, ".exe")
endif()

ADD_TEST(NAME test_myapp
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bin/myapp${EXE_SUFFIX} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test_myapp.txt
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
    )
```

But `WIN32` isn't available for some reason and it never appends the suffix.  Why isn't `WIN32` available?  Is the problem that ctest doesn't know about the settings from the toolchain file?  Does it not realize that WIN32 was declared?

I am able to use `if(WIN32)` elsewhere in my CMakeLists.txt file so long as `cmake.exe` is doing something with those lines, not `ctest.exe`.

In summary, `WIN32` is not set when ctest runs.

Is there a way to execute unit tests without involving ctest?  If it can't be trusted to do this right, maybe I don't use it anymore.

Comment: "But when I do this using the cross-compiled stuff, it can't find the .exe file." - Please, show the **exact error message**. Also, I am not sure whether `add_test` does anything when crosscompiling: cross-compilation usually means that one want to build a program, which cannot be run on the current (host) machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is totally incorrect:

> `SET(EXE_SUFFIX, ".exe")`

You have set the variable `EXE_SUFFIX,`, not `EXE_SUFFIX`. When you later expand `${EXE_SUFFIX}`, it comes back empty, so that entire `if (WIN32)` block is a no-op from the perspective of the rest of the program.

Comment: Do you think that such **typo** deserves the **answer**? I have seen a question with such extra comma nearly every week.

Comment: There might yet be other problems uncovered by fixing the typo. This is a starting point.

Comment: "There might yet be other problems uncovered by fixing the typo." - Well, in that case a **comment** seems to be more appropriate instead of the answer.

Comment: How, exactly, do you see the rest of this conversation going?

Comment: Extra comma was it.